# Getting a discord bot to mention other users

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am working on a bot to do some simple commands for my discord server and I haven't been able to figure out how to get the bot to mention people who aren't the author.

```
if message.content.startswith("+prank"):
        user = client.get_user_info(id)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, user.mention + 'mention')
```

When I try to run the command i come up with the error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Murk-Bot 2.0.py", line 130, in on_message
    await client.send_message(message.channel, user.mention + 'mention')
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'mention'
```

This happens if I use the command with a mention before, after, and not at all. If it gives some more context here are the imports I am using

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
```

Comment: Where are you getting `id` from?

Comment: It's a part of the discord import I believe.

Comment: If it's part of the `discord` import, then it should look something like `discord.id` or `from discord import id`. Do you use `id` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: No i don't, i'll see if any of those fix the problem.

Comment: I don't believe it will since to use `client.get_user_info` you need a string variable, which is what `id` should be. See here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info How are planning to use this +prank command?

Comment: What you suggested doesn't fix the problem. But instead upon some further research I found that `id` is in `import discord` so it is able to be called up. I think the true problem lies in the " AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'mention' " [link] (http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user)

Comment: But how are you getting `id`? If you are just getting it from `discord` import, your command will not work as how does it now which user to mention? Just using `id` does not do anything, you have to pass a string that corresponds to the user id.

How will +prank be used? For example, will "+prank User1" send a message from the bot that contains a mention to a user with username User1?

Comment: +prank will be used like you said but with an added message with something like "you got pranked"

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you are getting is caused by not awaiting a coroutine. `client.get_user_info` is a coroutine and must use `await`.

If you want "+prank" to work by mentioning by username, you can find a member object by using `server.get_member_named`.

Example code provided below. This will check the server the command was called from for the specified username and return the `member` object.

```
if message.content.startswith("+prank"):
    username = message.content[7:]
    member_object = message.server.get_member_named(username)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, member_object.mention + 'mention')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement commands without actually using `commands`.  Don't put everything in the `on_message` event.  If you're not sure how to use the `discord.ext.commands` module, you can look at the [documentation for the experimental rewrite branch](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/index.html).

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='+')

@bot.command()
async def prank(target: discord.Member):
    await bot.say(target.mention + ' mention')

bot.run('token')
```

You would use this command with `+prank Johnny`.  The bot would then respond in the same channel `@Johnny mention`